# send error message or without permission on the channel

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

My bot is having some problems with some servers, the problem is Missing Permissions, it happens when the bot tries to do a function that it does not have permission on the server, and to alert the users of the bot that it does not have permission to execute the command on the server, I put 2 functions so that it warns the member that it does not have enough permission, but it is not advancing because the bot does not send the message on the channel saying that it does not have permission

The first function where he tells the member that he is not allowed to create the invitation is

in  `if (!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE')) { return message.channel.send('I am not allowed to create invitations.');}`

And the second is

in `` } catch (e) { console.log(e) return message.reply(`The following error occurred :( \`${e.message}\` add the required permission \`MANAGE_INVITES\`.`); ``

````
const ms = require('parse-ms')
const { DiscordAPIError, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { invalid } = require("moment");
module.exports = {
  name: "jogar",
  description: "Set the prefix of the guild!",
  category: "economia",
  run: async (bot, message, args) => {
    
   
      if (!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE')) { return message.channel.send('Eu não\ tenho permissão para fazer isso!'); 
    }
    
    const { chunk } = require('../../functionsss');

    let guild = bot.guilds.cache.get("759003907858104350");
    let emoji = guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'loading');
    let emoji2 = guild.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === 'check');

    if(!message.member.voice.channel) return message.reply(`Você precisa está conectado ao um canal de voz para procurar partida!`)

    const voiceChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(c => c.type === 'voice');
let count = 0;

const vo = message.member.voice.channel.members.size

for (const [id, voiceChannel] of voiceChannels) count += voiceChannel.members.size; 

    let membro = message.author;
 
    let newInfo = args.join(' ');
    if (!newInfo) return message.reply('Insira o codigo da sala do among! **a!jogar BCETYJ**');
    if (newInfo.length > 6) return message.channel.send(`**Max \`6\` Caracteres permitidos!**`);
    let newsInfo = chunk(newInfo, 42).join('\n');
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    try {
    let channel = message.member.voice.channel;
      
        channel.createInvite({
            maxAge: 3600, // 0 = infinite expiration
            maxUses: 10 // 0 = infinite uses
          })
            .then(invite=>{
                embed
                .setTitle(`${emoji} Procurando partida..`)
                .setColor('RANDOM')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setDescription(`Pessoal <@${membro.id}> está procurando mais gente para jogar!
                \n<:info:775212992895254548> **Informações:**
                **・Canal:** ${channel}
                **・Codigo:** ${newsInfo}
                **・Jogadores:** ${vo}
                \n[Entrar na partida](https://discord.gg/${invite.code})`)
                .setThumbnail('https://attackofthefanboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Among-Us-3.jpg')
                message.channel.send(embed)
                message.react("✅");
            })

              } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
                return message.reply(`The following error occurred :( \`${e.message}\` add the required permission \`MANAGE_INVITES\`.`);
              }}}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before and I spent hours troubleshooting. I eventually figured out that it was the way that I was looking for permissions. Discord.js v12 has added many changes to this type of function. I suggest changing

```
(!message.guild.member(bot.user).hasPermission('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'))
```

to

```
(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("Create_Instant_Invite"){
  //rest of your code
}
```